# Array formula with more than 255 characters in length. reduced the length but getting output #NA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-formula

I have created an macro wherein array formula length was more than 255 characters. So I have reduced the length by adding DIM in macro. when I am running this coding; no error is coming and it's getting run successfully. However, output result is coming as "#NA".

```
 Sub Macro1()  
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Work\Projects\XYZ\New folder\NAL for Macro.xlsb"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


Dim X As Workbook
Dim U As Worksheet

Set X = Workbooks("NAL for Macro.xlsb")
Set U = X.Worksheets("Sheet1")

   Windows("Data.xlsx").Activate
      Sheets("Data").Select

   With ActiveSheet.Range("O2")
   .FormulaArray = _
    "=IFERROR(INDEX('[X]U'!C13,MATCH(1,('[X]U'!C8=RC[-8])*(LEFT('[X]U'!C3,15)=LEFT(RC[-13],15)),0)),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-8],'[X]U'!C8:C15,6,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-8],'[X]U'!C9:C15,5,0),(VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC[-13],15)&""*"",'[X]U'!C3:C15,11,0)))))"


 End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: @FaneDuru output is required in "O2" cell only I have changed with .Formula array  =... . Yes the formula is returning back with "#NA". Now I have notice along with "#NA" there is comment with yellow ! is coming in cell by mentioning "A Value is not available to the Formula or Function

Comment: In the FormulaArray you write `[X]U` but doesn't `U` already contain `X`?

Comment: You could use defined names to reduce your number of characters. In your formula X and U are just a X and a U, they don't refer to a workbook and a sheet